# Only keep the legal chars in a text using a .NET Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a list of legal characters and I want to remove all others chars from text.

```
// my legal chars. a-Z, numbers, space, _, - and percentage
string legalChars = "[\p{L}\p{Nd}_\-&#x20;&#x25;]*"

string text = "[update], Text with {illegal} chars such as: !? {}";
```

I do find a lot of examples for removing illegal chars. I want to do the opposite.

Comment: The opposite of 'removing illegal chars' is 'keeping illegal chars', but the question title is 'keep the legal chars'. Which one do you want ?

Comment: As the first line states:
"I have a list of legal characters and I want to remove all others chars from text."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
String trimmed = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\p{L}\p{Nd}_\-&#x20;&#x25;]", "");
```

Or:

```
private static readonly Regex RemovalPattern 
   = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\p{Nd}_\-&#x20;&#x25;]");

...


string trimmed = RemovalPattern.Replace(input, "");
```

Note that your regex of legal characters currently *doesn't* include space, contrary to the comment.

Comment: I think he was hoping &#x20; would match a space. &#x25; would be the percent char he's referring to (%).

Placing the dash (-) at the end of the list of characters would eliminate the need to escape it.

Also, if you're going to use the Regex a lot, the RegexOptions.Compiled option may improve performance:

private static readonly Regex RemovalPattern = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\p{Nd}_ %-]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Comment: Thanks Arne. Jon has put me on the right track. But I still had to replace the XML save notation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through the string yourselfa and check for each character if it's a legal char append the char to a new string (for example with stringbuilder)

Comment: Whehe Regex is way simpeler, never mind this post. Never knew you can replace with regex (never use it)